# Spring Boot application has about 20 ObjectMappers

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I'm trying to configure the Jackson `ObjectMapper` in a Spring Boot application. I've tried various approaches as suggested here and in the documentation (e.g. using a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` or `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` `@Bean`). I want to register a mixin to exclude some fields in the `DefaultMessageSourceResolvable` class, which should be fairly straightforward.

However, by placing a breakpoint in the `ObjectMapper` constructor, I've seen that there are about 20 instances being created. Multiple instances of `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` are created as well.

Creating a bean of the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` type does not work either; it gets invoked, but the mixin is not registered in the instance which is eventually used for serialization.

Is it normal to have so many instances of these classes? If it is, what might be the reason that my customization efforts fail? If not, what might be wrong and how may it be fixed?

Comment: Is it possible that the ObjectMappers are created in a non spring-related way. You are just checking the constructor, but there is nothing stopping anyone from just calling `new` on it, that doesn't mean that the OM will be managed by spring. Test your injection point and make sure that the OM injected is the one that you created.

Comment: From the stack traces of your breakpoints you should see where those are created. A common problem could be the default constructor of `RestTemplate`. It would be preferred to use the one explicitly configuring the message converters, and specify a common `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.

One of the solutions I've tried is to configure the ObjectMapper using this:

`@Configuration
    public class JacksonConfig {@Autowired
 ObjectMapper mapper;
 
 @PostConstruct
 public void configure() {
  mapper.addMixIn(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable.class, DefaultMessageSourceResolvableMixin.class);
 }

}`

I've noticed that the ObjectMapper instance autowired here is different from the one that's actually used during serialization. Could you point me in a direction to solve this?